# Using 'in' modifier in workfront api in python with multiple values

Tags: python, api, workfront-api

I using the python-workfront api to search for existing issues
The following code is a simple example of the search I am using and works:

```
issues = session.search(api.Issue,name=nameSearch, name_Mod='contains',status='INP',status_Mod='notin')
```

When I try to add multiple values for the 'notin' modifier, the search returns all values that match the name criteria listed but seems to ignore the status filter:

```
issues = session.search(api.Issue,name=nameSearch, name_Mod='contains',status=['INP','NEW'],status_Mod='notin')
```

What is the appropriate syntax for using the 'in' or 'notin' modifier?

Comment: Was able to solve this using the workfrontapi-plus module for Python.  Thanks Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this using the workfrontapi-plus module for Python. Thanks Craig